# Can I make a facebook app when user post a comment on my website, it also appear on their profile ( with their approval )

Tags: facebook

I plan to style facebook comment to something more appealing, after doing research for a while, I realize that I can not do that, so I think about another solution, I style my website comment system and when people comment on a post on my site, it also appear on their profile ( with their approval of course), can anyone tell me a solution for this ? I am really thankful cause I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an application that allows you to post on the users behalf.

You need to start with the `FB API` The only way you are going to get through this is by trial and error.

This is what you will have to do,

Register your app with Facebook and get your `app id and secret`. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/)

Download `FB API` [Here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)

Read FB API [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Build a login allowing your user to login with Facebook.

Then

Request the permissions needed to post on the users behalf.

This is a working login script requesting the permission you will need.

Read every line and change what needs to be change. Add files that are missing. Take note of any variables and figure out what they are or what they hold.

Make sure your file paths are correct when requesting the required files and class from the FB API.

```
<?php

// include required classes from Facebook SDK
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

// Called class with namespace
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id_here','secret_here' );

 // login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.Your.URL.com' );


// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data with response           
$graphObject = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}
?>


 <?php
// This is how users will login and logout
  if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://www.YourSitePathTOLogout/fbLogout.php' ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorRed"> Logout</span>' . "&nbsp" .  $graphObject['first_name'] . "&nbsp" . $graphObject['last_name'] . '</a></dd>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'publish_stream, addPermissionsLikeThis, AddMore, AddMore, orDelteThese, KeepFirstOne' ) ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorBlue"> Login With Facebook</a></dd>';
}
            ?>
```